# Extended fields when creating a Scapy Layer (chained bytes)

Tags: python, scapy

I am trying to create a Layer in Scapy for a protocol which has a custom field type called "Extended Field".

The principle is quite simple but I struggle with implementation.

Principle is:

- First byte of the field is at a known position followed by a variable number of bytes.
- The number of bytes is not defined anywhere in the frame.
- If LSB of a byte is "1" then the following byte is part of the field
- If LSB of a byte is "0" then it is the end of the field.
- Result is a bit field with concatenated 7 MSB bits of each byte

I made a picture to make it simpler:

[Extended Field Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIsPZ.png)

I have read a lot of stuff about variable length fields in Scapy but as far as I understand this does not cover this case.

Do you think it can be implemented in a Scapy Layer? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have tons of ways of doing this, it depends on the data type that you want to be able to use afterwards: would you like to get a bytes string containing all the bytes ? Each byte as a number (aka an array of number) ? Each byte as a packet ?

Comment: In fact, each bit of the extendedfield is a flag saying if a certain data is present in the payload or not. I guess either a list of bits, or a byte string will be ok.

I am trying something by defining a new Field type creating a subclass of Field. I think it will work, I'll let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I answer myself after a bit of digging into Scapy.

Here is a solution that works (maybe not optimal, but enough for me):

```
from scapy.all import *

class LSBExtendedField(Field):
    """
    LSB Extended Field
    ------------------

    This type of field has a variable number of bytes. Each byte is defined as follows:
    - The 7 MSB bits are data
    - The LSB is an extenesion bit
        * 0 means it is last byte of the field ("stopping bit")
        * 1 means there is another byte after this one ("forwarding bit")

    To get the actual data, it is necessary to navigate the binary data byte per byte and to check if LSB until 0
    """

    """
    Converts bytes to field
    """
    def str2extended(self, l=""):
        s = []
        # First bit is the stopping bit at zero
        bits = 0b0
        # Then we retrieve 7 bits. If "forwarding bit" is 1, then we continue on another byte
        i = 0
        for c in l:
            s.append(hex(c & 0xfe))
            bits = bits << 7 | (int(c) >> 1)
            if not int(c)&0b1:
                end = l[i+1:]
                break
            i=i+1
        return end, bits

    """
    Converts field to bytes
    """
    def extended2str(self, l):
        l=int(l)
        s = []
        # First bit is the stopping bit at zero
        bits = 0b0
        # Then we group bits 7 by 7 adding the "forwarding bit" if necessary
        i=1
        while (l>0):
            if i%8 == 0:
                s.append(bits)
                bits = 0b1
                i=0
            else:
                bits = bits | (l & 0b1) << i
                l = l >> 1
            i = i+1
        s.append(bits)
        s.reverse()

        result = "".encode()
        for x in s:
            result = result + struct.pack(">B", x)
        return result

    def i2m(self, pkt, x):
        return self.extended2str(x)

    def m2i(self, pkt, x):
        return self.str2extended(x)[1]

    def addfield(self, pkt, s, val):
        return s+self.i2m(pkt, val)

    def getfield(self, pkt, s):
        return self.str2extended(s)
```